# Server becomes unresponsive after several days

Tags: centos, dedicated-server, supermicro

I have a dedicated server that becomes unresponsive after several days of running-time.
Sometimes it's 1 day and sometimes it's 5 days but it always happens and I can neither reach the server via ssh nor log into the supermicro control panel.

I have to power off and on the server from my provider's control panel to make the server accessible again.

The server isn't running something heavy, just a LAMP setup.

How can I diagnose this, to see what's wrong and to fix the issues?

The only prominent thing I found is in the `messages` file:

```
Aug 16 18:01:50 server1 kernel: sbridge: HANDLING MCE MEMORY ERROR
Aug 16 18:01:50 server1 kernel: CPU 0: Machine Check Exception: 0 Bank 7: 8c00004000010093
Aug 16 18:01:50 server1 kernel: TSC 0 ADDR 2804ab80 MISC 214042c286 PROCESSOR 0:306e4 TIME 1439766110 SOCKET 0 APIC 0
Aug 16 18:01:50 server1 kernel: EDAC MC0: CE row 6, channel 0, label "CPU_SrcID#0_Channel#3_DIMM#0": 1 Unknown error(s): memory read on FATAL area : cpu=0 Err=0001:0093 (ch=3), addr = 0x2804ab80 => socket=0, Channel=3(mask=8), rank=2
```

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: Where / what should I look for?

Comment: It's your server. You should know where it keeps its logs. :-) Depending on your distribution and logging configuration, you should typically review everything in /var/log and below that has been modified in, say, the last five minutes before the crash, looking for anything unusual or mentioning words like "error" or "panic", or any pattern that correlates to the times when the server becomes unresponsive.

Comment: I updated my post with the results I found scanning the logs. Could this mean a RAM module is broken?

Comment: @maddo7: Have u found any solution?
I have the same problem , The box is a supermicro, Ubuntu 14.04.3 X64 server, no heavy load, just a reverse proxy,
`EDAC MC0: 3 CE memory read error on CPU_SrcID#0_Channel#3_DIMM#0 (channel:3 slot:0 page:0x792b0 offset:0x8c0 grain:32 syndrome:0x0 -  OVERFLOW area:DRAM err_code:0001:0093 socket:0 channel_mask:8 rank:0)`

Have u found any solution?

Comment: Could you add the output of `ipmitool sel list`?

Answer (score 1):

The machine reports a RAM error and even tells you which module is affected.
Recommendation: replace that module and see if the problem goes away.